# Select matches between a table and a unnest(string_to_array) semi-colon separated table

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I have one table "cosings" with "CAS_No" column and "INCI_name" column. The other table is a table with semi-colon separated values ALIAS as "semicolon_separated".
I am trying to match "INCI_name" and "semicolon_separated" and get "CAS_No".

```
SELECT 
    "CAS_No" 
FROM 
    cosings 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
        (SELECT 
            TRIM(unnest(string_to_array(ingredients, ';'))) AS semicolon_separated 
        FROM 
            products 
        WHERE 
            id = 1
        ) AS ing_table 
        ON cosings."INCI_name" = ing_table.semicolon_separated;
```

I am getting the right number of rows but all of the rows are empty.

Product Table:

```
id | ingredients
 1    chemical_1 ; chemical_2; chemical_3
 2    compound_5; compound_10
```

Cosing Table:

```
INCI_name | CAS_No
chemical_1    111
chemical_2    222
compound_5    555
```

If I select id = 1 from Product table, I should get:

```
CAS_No
 111
 222
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem (See *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=56bcf1df6673db3cd79e4f759fe36eb5)*). Please, provide some sample data that shows your case...

Comment: @joanolo That's exactly the result I am trying to get. But the result rows are still empty. They are all citext as well so no issue with that... The data tables you created are exactly correct. The "ingredient" column is correct too with semi-colons.

Comment: `citext` shouldn't be a problem, but, for the sake of having found a possible bug with them: What happens if you change the `citext` to `text`?

Comment: Apart from the fact that it should be a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, your query works fine with your sample data.